# sending an image as a base64 encoded to google cloud vision API using the nodejs client library

Tags: node.js, base64, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, client-library

I am using nodejs client library of Google cloud Web detection API and I wanted to pass a base64 encoded image to it but there is no documentation about it. I tried it using simple API calls and it works but as client library is neater I was wondering if they have implemented it there as well. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you should be able to send the [base64-encoded image](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/base64) using the [Cloud Vision API Client Library for Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries).

When using the [`webDetection()` method](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/vision/0.15.x/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient#webDetection) from your `ImageAnnotatorClient` instance, the `request` field should include an `AnnotateImageRequest` object which, on its part, includes an `image` object. That `image` object has the structure represented in this [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/vision/0.15.x/google.cloud.vision.v1.html#.Image). And as you can see, it can either include the `source` where the image is located or the `content` representation as a stream of bytes.

Also, if you have a look at the [*`google.cloud.vision.v1.Image` definition in proto format*](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/cloud/vision/v1/image_annotator.proto#L132), you will see that indeed it takes as an image definition either the *source* or the *content*.

Comment: You are right, thanks a lot, I was sending the base64 in a wrong format. I got it working with client library too.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

So a workaround will be to just use the API to pass base64:

```
request({
    url: "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate",
    method: "POST",
    qs: {
      key: "your key"
    },
    json: true,
    body: {
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "content": place your base64 here(without prefix)
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "WEB_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```